# Get tree view of elements in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have to build tree like structure for elements inside a div.

For example I had below html code:

```
<div id="main1">
   <div class="sub1"></div>
   <div class="sub2">
     <div id="sub_sub"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="sub3"></div>   
</div>
```

For the above code I have to get Tree view like as shown below

```
#main1
  .sub1
  .sub2
     #sub_sub
  .sub3
```

Names of html elements in tree view may be ID name or Class name. How can we do this with JQuery.

I have tried using jquery each function but its not giving tree like structure.
Example:

```
          $('div').each(function(){
              if($(this).attr('id')!=undefined)
                 $('#tree').append($(this).attr('id'));
             else
                 $('#tree').append($(this).attr('class'));
        });
```

Its giving like shown below

```
                 main1
                 sub1
                 sub2
                 sub_sub
                 sub3
```

It should give complete tree view of html elements how can I do that.

Comment: Ya it's understood that you want it to happen using JQuery, but what are the base rules. I mean on what basis, like there should one main class, three subMenus, 3-2-1 sub_sub menu respectively.

Comment: Here is something you could look at to get a vague idea http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/hzuwnye1/

Comment: @divy3993 No rules. Dynamically it have to give child/sub child elements.

Comment: @depperm I had added the code I worked on. Can you please help me in the issue of knowing what are the child's of a element and put them in a tree like view.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class^="sub"]').css('margin-left','20px');
    $('.sub_sub').css('margin-left','40px');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main1">Main
   <div class="sub1">Sub1</div>
   <div class="sub2">Sub2
     <div class="sub_sub">Sub2.1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="sub3">Sub3
    <div class="sub_sub">Sub3.1</div>
    </div>   
    
</div>
```

Comment: It should do dynamically, mean it have to identify which is child/sub-child element automatically not on by class/id name.